# Java, how to create a way for the program to count how many times a gender appears

Tags: java

So I wrote this and besides the fact that I need to clean it up, I just need to write a way for the program to count how many times either gender appears. For example, if the user says I want 5 kids and the program predicts that they'll have 3 boys and two girls, how can I get the program to write
boys:3
girls:2

```
     int coinFlips = input.nextInt();
     int headCount = 0;
     int consecutiveHeads = 0;
     while (coinFlips < 1)
     {

         coinFlips = input.nextInt();
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < coinFlips; i++)
     {
         int coinFace = randomNumber.nextInt(2);
         if (1 == coinFace)
         {
        
             System.out.print( "boy" );
             headCount++;
             consecutiveHeads++;
         }
         else
         {
        
              System.out.print( "girl" );
              consecutiveHeads = 0;
       

         }
         
}
```

}

Comment: You already know how many boys you have because for every "boy" you increment `headCount` So just use that variable and print its value. (And for girls you just have to do the elementary school math problem off subtracting the number of boys from your total coin flips...which should be doable)

Comment: The question is incomplete. For your request "get the program to write boys:3 girls:2", do you mean to output the result to console or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

After your for loop.

```
System.out.printf("Boys: %d  Girls %d%n",headCount, coinFlips-headCount);
```

But more importantly, why are you doing this?

```
 while (coinFlips < 1)
 {
        coinFlips = input.nextInt();
 }
```

Wouldn't an informative message be useful to help out the user as to why their count wasn't accepted?